# Excel Function format

Tags: string, function, vba, excel, function-signature

I am quite new to writing functions in excel (been mainly coding sub procedures).

I was wondering what the following function declaration means?

`public function function_name(args as string) as string`

I understand everything up to the second instance of `as string`. This is something new to me and I am not sure how this is different to just declaring:

`public function function_name(args as string)`

Comment: `public function function_name(args as string)` is exactly the same as `public function function_name(ByRef args as string) as variant`

Comment: @ooo I think that's has been mentioned in my answer already :)

Comment: Really, are you sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public function function_name(args as string) as string`

- **public** is the access definition. public means accessible across the VBA Project
- **function** means that is it a function (*meaning it is supposed to return something*)
- **function_name** is the name of a function (can't start with 1 or underscore)
- **args** is the local parameter name to be used within the body of function
- **args as String** indicates that the function is expecting the `args` to be of a `String` type
- **...) As String** indicates that the function will be returning a `String` data type. So if you have had dimensioned a String type variable you would be able to assign a value to it using the function.

---

the standard (default) declaration without explicitly specifying the type to be returned returns a `Variant`

It's the same as declaring a variable without specifying its type.

`Dim aVariable`

with is equivalent to

`Dim aVariable as Variant`

because `Variant` is the default type.

so the `as Variant` always exist unless there is a different type specified. And because it's default you do not have to explicitly *code* it.

It's somehow similar to `Range("A1").Value` and `Range("A1")` - both are the same because `.Value` is the default property of a `Range` object.

What happens now is the compiler evaluates what value goes into the `aVariable` under the hood and assigns that type to the variable.

Let's say you have

```
Sub Main()

    Dim varVariable
    Dim strVariable As String

    varVariable = "hello world"
    strVariable = "hello world"

    MsgBox "varVariable is of " & TypeName(varVariable) & " type" & vbCrLf & _
           "strVariable is of " & TypeName(strVariable) & " type"

End Sub
```

Like I've said now both are of `String` type

[image]

---

Not sure how familiar with for example C# you are but in C# you declare the **return type** of a function right after the access modifier ie.

```
public string myFunction(string args)
```

so in VB/VBA the second `as String` is equal to the first `string` (*right after public*) in C#

in C# you would use a `return` keyword while in VBA you replace the `return` keyword with the function **name**. Therefore in VBA a very basic sample

```
Public Function ReturnFirst3Characters(args As String) As String
    ReturnFirst3Characters = IIf(Len(args) > 2, Left(args, 3), args)
End Function
```

Function returns first 3 characters of the string you have passed to it (*if the string is longer then 3 characters, if not it returns the string you passed to the function*)

Comment: Good answer as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

The second "as" indicates the type the function returns.
That function returns a string, you can return a value inside the function in this way:

`function_name="Value"`

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx :

```
Function RectangleArea(Height As Double, Width As Double) As Double
    RectangleArea = Height * Width
End Function
```

> This function takes as inputs two Double type variables, Height and
>   Width, and returns a Double as its result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with `Procedure`s, think of a `Function` as a `Procedure` that returns a value.  The `as String` as the end **indicates what *type* of value is returned.**

The *way* you return a value is to use the name of the function as if it were a variable:

```
Public Function ConvertToUpperCase(str as string) as string
    ConvertToUpperCase = UCase(str)
End Function
```